# Multiple images in inkscspe

Tags: inkscape

I have 4 png or pdf images and I want to create a pdf image in which I put the first in the upper left corner, the second in the upper right corner and the same for the third and fourth images in the subsequent row.Even if it may be very easy, I am completely new to inkscape and I do not find any reference in which this task is performed.
Thank you for any possible advice!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need the align window (that you can find in the "object" scrolling menu) and to switch it to relative to "page".

[image: the align and distribute window in inkscape]